# pass argument from url to view

Tags: 6, views

I have a view with 5 results limit and a more link to show all nodes. The more link goes to xxx/yyy/123. Number 123 is the nid of node, that listed nodes are referencing to. 
On a current page, lets say- xxx/yyy/123 I would like to use another view that can print the name of node with 123 nid. 
I tried to set a view using default argument - node id from url and use a field with title but it seems that the number from such url it is not picked up as an argument. Can anybody give some advice? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Views generally gets node id from url when url format seems to be `node/nid`

For your case, select '`Raw value from URL`' in `Provide default value` section and select path component as 3 as nid lies in 3rd url arg. Your views should be getting the desired nid now.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thank you. this solution seems to work for drupal 7, I can not see option - raw value from url. Anyway - I used %1 in field as an argument and it is working as expected.